# 503 only on products detail pages with images

Tags: magento2, extensions, admin-panel, product-detail-page, ssl-certificate

I am using **Magento 2.2.7**
Can't visit **product details pages** or edit them if any **image** was added to **product**.

Also when I am **login** into **admin part** and go into **Content - Configuration** - Edit theme. Page loading infinitely. I have tried all browsers and have also tried to change theme in **database**.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eghK.png)

I think that this could be related to Magento update or **ssl certificate** installation.

I wasn't able to find any helpful information in logs. Have tried to remove **extensions**. Have tried to flush **cache**. Have tried even to restore website from backup.

Answer (score 0):

That was wrong php configuration. After resetting php.ini to defaults now everything is working